# MySQL - get rows with same ID but different specific values on another column

Tags: mysql

I know the title isn't very helpful, part of the reason I'm having trouble figuring this out on my own is I can't figure out how to word it, so I can't google it.

Anyway, I'm making a Netflix style website with movies and TV shows ripped from my DVD collection. It's a LAMP stack running off my Raspberry Pi. I want to have the option to search by genre by selecting genres from a bunch of check boxes. I want it to work so that if I check "horror" and "comedy", the search results only return movies/TV shows that have BOTH those genres, not either/or.

So I have a couple MySQL tables, THR_MOVIE, THR_SHOW, and THR_GENRE. The structures of THR_MOVIE and THR_SHOW aren't really important for this question, just know that each movie/TV show takes up just one row and has a unique ID. Here's the structure of THR_GENRE:

```
CREATE TABLE `THR_GENRE` (
`media_id` INT(7) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
`genre` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
`media_type` ENUM('movie','show') NOT NULL,
`date_added` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
PRIMARY KEY (`media_id`, `genre`, `media_type`))
```

Obviously if media_type is 'movie', then media_id is a THR_MOVIE ID and not a THR_SHOW ID. Some example data from the genres table might look like this:

```
row 1: media_id=12, genre='horror', media_type='movie'
row 2: media_id=12, genre='comedy', media_type='movie'
```

So how would this query work? I need to get the movie data, so I need to join THR_MOVIE with THR_GENRE to get the movies, then do the same with THR_SHOW and THR_GENRE to get the TV shows.

Comment: update your question add  the expected  result ,,and the query you actually are using  ..

Answer (score 0):

You might use `left outer join`:

```
select
  *
from
  THE_GENRE g
left outer join
  THR_MOVIE m
    on m.id = g.media_id
    and g.media_type = 'movie'
left outer join
  THR_SHOW s
    on s.id = g.media_id
    and g.media_type = 'show'
```

Query will return columns for both movie and show tables. Code which consume this query result will need to check media_type value and use `movie` table columns if type is 'movie' or `show` table columns if type is `show`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the response, but I just figured it out myself.

```
select *
from THR_GENRE
where (genre='horror'
or genre='comedy')
and media_type='movie'
group by media_id
having count(*)=2
```

Obviously my PHP script will have to create the query string with count(*)=X, where X is some variable holding the number of genres searched for.